# KendoUI: Multiple Grids in a foreach loop (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

Using KendoUI, MVC4.

I need to display a number of grids, but when I try this, it renders nothing:

```
@foreach (TheItem item in Model)
{
    Html.Kendo().Grid(item.DisplayList)
    .Name(item.GetHashCode().ToString())
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Status");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Value).Title(" ");
        });    
}
```

When I try with just a single entity, it works fine:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model[0].DisplayList) 
    .Name("ItemGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Status");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Value).Title(" ");
        }))
```

Is there a trick to getting many grids to get rendered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the **@()** razor operator surrounding the Grid declaration. Without it you are not rendering anything to the output.

Either use the **@()** operator or call the **Render()** method of the Widget.